# Concatenate numbers in binary

Tags: python

When converting a number in binary in Python what you get is the following:

```
b = bin(77)
print(b)  # 0b1001101
```

When I was expecting `01001101`. I am guessing that the `b` is there to let Python know that this is a binary number and not some integer. And that is ok **within Python** but what is considered safe practise here if you want to communicate with the outside world? *This might be a silly example but online converters for instance do not recognise the above binary*.

Would simply removing `b` always do the trick? Because I seem to be running into problems trying to code the Ascii85 encoder/decoder where concatenations of binary numbers take place. You can take a look at this example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85).

My code is this case produces the following:

```
ch = 'Man '
list_ = [ord(x) for x in ch]  # [77, 97, 110, 32]
binary_repr = ''.join(bin(x) for x in list_)  # 0b10011010b11000010b11011100b100000
# When it should be                                01001101011000010110111000100000
```

Notice that simply replacing the `b` with nothing doesn't quite cut it here. This is probably some dumm mistake but can someone clear things up for me?

Comment: no, trimming _two first characters_ will do the trick.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski but trimming the first 2 characters would result in 7 digits. How can that be?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis `bin` doesn't care about bytes, it just produces the shortest bitstring that represents the number.  `bin(1) -> 0b1` [Some history of `0b`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17535861/6779307)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I see. Thank all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> format(b, '08b')
```

Where b is your number and '08b' is the number of bit you want to use representing your number, if the parameter is #08b instead of 08b, you get the 0b in front of the number.

use format in every further operation and you should be good!

Comment: or: `print "{0:b}".format(77)`

Comment: @alfasin I like it better that way too.

Comment: You are right, I forgot about that, just answered the first solution that came through my mind, it's been a long time since I last used phyton tbh

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't

```
str(b)[2:]
```

do the job?

But you'll maybe better do:

```
"{0:b}".format(77)
```