# Binary with Python letter b delete or what its meaning?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just started with Python and want to find the binary code for any given character in a text file. The problem I encountered is when it prints the binary there is a "b" in the binary.

```
file = open("textfile.txt","w")
file.write("Hello World ")
file.write("This our new text file")
file.write("and this is another line. ")
file.write("Why? Because we can.")
file.close()
with open("textfile.txt") as file:
    data=file.readline()
data_vector = list(data)
binary_data_vector = map(bin, bytearray(data_vector))
print(binary_data_vector)
```

This is the output I am currently getting:

```
['0b1001000', '0b1100101', '0b1101100', '0b1101100', '0b1101111', '0b100000', '0b1010111', '0b1101111', '0b1110010', '0b1101100', '0b1100100', '0b100000', '0b1010100', '0b1101000', '0b1101001', '0b1110011', '0b100000', '0b1101111', '0b1110101', '0b1110010', '0b100000', '0b1101110', '0b1100101', '0b1110111', '0b100000', '0b1110100', '0b1100101', '0b1111000', '0b1110100', '0b100000', '0b1100110', '0b1101001', '0b1101100', '0b1100101', '0b1100001', '0b1101110', '0b1100100', '0b100000', '0b1110100', '0b1101000', '0b1101001', '0b1110011', '0b100000', '0b1101001', '0b1110011', '0b100000', '0b1100001', '0b1101110', '0b1101111', '0b1110100', '0b1101000', '0b1100101', '0b1110010', '0b100000', '0b1101100', '0b1101001', '0b1101110', '0b1100101', '0b101110', '0b100000', '0b1010111', '0b1101000', '0b1111001', '0b111111', '0b100000', '0b1000010', '0b1100101', '0b1100011', '0b1100001', '0b1110101', '0b1110011', '0b1100101', '0b100000', '0b1110111', '0b1100101', '0b100000', '0b1100011', '0b1100001', '0b1101110', '0b101110']
```

So my question is how can I get rid of "b" so it prints only 8 bits for each character. And if you know why this happens, please explain!.

Comment: `bin(..)` generates a **string** for an integer of the form `0b...` with the remainder bits. This is done so you can immediately inject the output back in the interpreter.

Comment: Some string slicing and list comprehension? `bits = [just_bits[2:] for just_bits in binary_data_vectory]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641091/concatenate-numbers-in-binary

Comment: i am using version Python 2.7.13

Comment: BTW, you should not use `file` as a variable name in Python 2 because that shadows the built-in `file` type. Shadowing the built-in type names (like `list`, `str`, `set`, `file`, etc) can lead to mysterious bugs with cryptic error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `bin` function returns the binary representation of a number, prefixed with `0b` which makes such a representation suitable directly for input in Python source code.

It is not what we want most of the time, so one valid thing would be to strip the first 2 chars of each string. But then there is another issue with `bin`: it only encodes as many bits of a number as needed to represent it. That means that ASCII characters would be encoded in 7 binary digits, when we usually want 8 bits on the representation.

The alternative is to use string formatting itself for creating the representation. The `.format` string method allows you not only to ask for the binary (rather than decimal) representation of a number be printed, but further allows you to specify how many digits you want by typing in the leading zeros in the format string:

```
binary_data_vector = ["{:08b}".format(number) for number in bytearray(data_vector)]
```

(Take time to look at [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)  - they look strange at first, but are far more powerful and readable than using the `map` and `filter` functions - the above line, for example, would require specifying a lambda function to be written using `map` as you had it)

Comment: Another thing: I'd suggest learning Python3 instead of Python 2 at this point in time. I can infer you are using Python 2 - because in Python 3 your "casting" to bytearray would not work as is (but would not be needed as well, if the file is read correctly)